# Hosting React page on S3 and making REST api calls to server on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

### Background

I am trying to deploy a dummy application with React frontend and Django backend interacting via REST api. I have done the following:

- Use a S3 bucket to host static website and deploy my react code to it
- Put Cloudfront for S3 bucket - set up certificate and changed my domain name (from GoDaddy) to link to this address
- Kicked off Elastic Beanstalk environment following the python environment tutorial of AWS
- Set up Postgres RDS and linked the Django server with it

So now I can do the following

- Access my frontend using https via my domain name (https://www.example.com)
- Access django admin site using the path of elastic beanstalk and update items

i.e. each component is up and running

### Problem

I am having trouble with:

- Making a secure REST API call from the static page to Elastic Beanstalk environment. Before I set up certificates I could easily make REST API calls.
- The guides I can find usually involve putting a domain name for Elastic Beanstalk, which I imagine does not apply to my case (or does it?)
- I tried to follow this [faq](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html) and updated configuration in load balancer that accepts 443 https and redirects to 80 http. But I am using same certificate as from CloudFront, which does not sound right to me.

Would appreciate help with

- how to solve the above ssl connection issue
- or is there a better architecture for what I'm trying to achieve here?

According to [Request a certificate in ACM for Elastic Beanstalk backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49118138/request-a-certificate-in-acm-for-elastic-beanstalk-backend), it sounds like I have to use a subdomain and request a certificate for that subdomain, and use Cloud 53 to direct requests to that subdomain to Elastic Beanstalk environment. Would that be the case?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default EB url will HTTP only. To use HTTPS you need to **deploy SSL certificate on your ALB**.

In order to do that you need a **custom domain**, because you can only associated an SSL certificates with **domains that you control**. Thus, normally you would get a domain (you seem to already have one from godaday). So in this case you can setup a subdomain (e.g. `api.my-domian.com`) on godady. Then you can use AWS ACM to register a free public SSL certificate for `api.my-domian.com`.

Once the certificate is verified, using either DNS (easier) or email technique, you deploy it on your ALB using HTTPs listener. Obviously you will need to point `api.my-domian.com` to the EB's https url. You can also **redirect** on your ALB http traffic from port 80 to 443 to always use https.

Then in your front-end application you only use `https://api.my-domian.com`, not the original EB url.

There can be also CORS issues alongside this, so have to be vary of them as well.